# Silverlight Toolkit Chart: Assign Hyperlink to Axis

Tags: silverlight, xaml, charts, silverlight-toolkit, styling

I have a simple Silverlight Toolkit Chart which is bound to a collection of the following type:

```
public class ChartItemClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

I can get a Chart to display the Name (X-axis) and Value (Y-axis) correctly, but I would like the labels on the X-axis to be HyperlinkButtons to the Url property.  The X-axis label should be something like the following:

```
<HyperlinkButton Content="*Name Property Here*" NavigateUri="*Url Property Here*" TargetName="_blank"></HyperlinkButton>
```

I found an example which allowed me to set the AxisLabelStyle for the X-axis so the Labels are now HyperlinkButtons.  The problem is I haven't been able to assign/bind the Url property as the NavigateUri.  Any ideas?

Comment: Tags on SO are not comprehensible, even I don't know the difference between 'charting' and 'chart'. Anyway the question is answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first I will post the complete code and after that the explanation.

```
   <UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="hyperlinkStyle" TargetType="charting:AxisLabel">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:AxisLabel">
                    <HyperlinkButton Content="{Binding Name}" NavigateUri="{Binding Url}" TargetName="_blank"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<charting:Chart>
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <charting:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}" IndependentValueBinding="{Binding}">
            <charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
                <charting:CategoryAxis Orientation="X" AxisLabelStyle="{StaticResource hyperlinkStyle}" />
            </charting:ColumnSeries.IndependentAxis>
        </charting:ColumnSeries>
    </charting:Chart.Series>
</charting:Chart>
```

The trick is in this line:

```
IndependentValueBinding="{Binding}"
```

Using this binding you pass a whole object to the independent axis, not just a property.
And after that you can get properties of a bound object in the control template of label:

```
Content="{Binding Name}" NavigateUri="{Binding Url}"
```

The `Binding` keyword instead of the `TemplateBinding` looks strange, but it is permitted and it works.
And there is one remark: the `Url` property must contain the `http` prefix. It doesn't work with `www`.

Comment: That was it.  Your code is pretty much exactly what I had (I apologize for not including it in the original message and making you type the whole thing) except for the IndependentValueBinding="{Binding}".  Thanks for the help!