# Customize WPF Toolkit column chart

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, charts

I want to create a column chart using the WPF toolkit, but I want to hide the Y axis and display the dependant value for each column below the X value.

Is this possible?? If not, what other way could be used to get this result??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can hide the Y-axis. You should add the y-axis explicitly to the `Axes` property of the chart and set the `Opacity` property, like this:

```
<charting:Chart.Axes>
    <charting:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Opacity="0" />
</charting:Chart.Axes>
```

As to the second question, you should change the `AxisLabelStyle` property. I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5465654/427225), you can look at the code and change the ControlTemplate according to your needs.

The template will look something like this, don't forget change bindings:

```
<Style x:Key="twoLabelsStyle" TargetType="charting:AxisLabel">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="charting:AxisLabel">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Month}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Number}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Anyway if it will not still work - add your source code to your question, it can help much better.